# What is the format for piping a message into sendmail?

Tags: shell, email, sendmail, echo

I am using the following command to create messages on the fly, and send them:

```
echo "Subject:Hello \n\n I would like to buy a hamburger\n" | sendmail email@example.com
```

It seems that when you send the information from a file, by doing something like:

```
sendmail email@example.com mail.txt
```

Then sendmail sees each line as a header, and parses it. But the way I sent it above, everything ends up in the subject line.

If one wants to echo a message complete with headers, into sendmail, then what is the format ? How does one do it ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your `echo` statement should really output newlines not the sequence `\` followed by `n`. You can do that by providing the `-e` option:

```
echo -e "Subject:Hello \n\n I would like to buy a hamburger\n" | sendmail email@example.com
```

To understand what is the difference have a look at the output from the following two commands:

```
echo "Subject:Hello \n\n I would like to buy a hamburger\n"
echo -e "Subject:Hello \n\n I would like to buy a hamburger\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

"Here document" in shell scripts (You compose message headers and body)

```
#!/bin/sh
TO=email@example.com
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i $TO <<MAIL_END
Subject: Hello
To: $TO

I would like to buy a hamburger
MAIL_END
```

Message body from external file

```
#!/bin/sh
TO=email@example.com
BODY_FILE=mail.txt
(cat - $BODY_FILE)<<HEADERS_END | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $TO
Subject: Hello
To: $TO

HEADERS_END
```